# Geometric transformation of ImageAlign

Tags: image-processing

Hi I am trying to find the geometric transformation following an image align. However I am getting I am not sure how to deal with the crop aspect.

For example:
Here are the 2 images I am trying to align.
[image]

Aligned 2nd image in regards to the first using ImageAlign. It has a slight crop on the right side
[image]

The third image is using the geometric transformation.

However for the third image when using the GeometricTransform method I am not sure how to incorporate the crop.
[image]